# What should I replace "GUILayer" component with?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to open a 5.5.3f1 project into 2019.3.2f1 for multiple reasons.

The only remaining issues I have are related to the recent removal of the "GUILayer" component, here are the last errors I get :

Errors:

[image: Errors]

(end of the two cut lines)

End of lines:

[image: End of lines]

All these errors come from the same script : "SteamVR_Camera.cs". Here are this script's namespaces and problematic areas :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using Valve.VR;
```

---

```
var guiLayer = GetComponent<GUILayer>();
if (guiLayer != null)
{
    DestroyImmediate(guiLayer);
    head.gameObject.AddComponent<GUILayer>();
}
```

---

```
var guiLayer = head.GetComponent<GUILayer>();
if (guiLayer != null)
{
    DestroyImmediate(guiLayer);
    gameObject.AddComponent<GUILayer>();
}
```

Do you know what I have to use instead of GUILayer for my project to compile ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Please Note: This component relates to legacy methods for drawing UI 
>   textures and images to the screen. You should use Unity’s up-to-date
>   [UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html) instead. This is also unrelated to the [IMGUI
>   system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html).

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUILayer.html

Comment: Thanks, the problematic script comes from a previous version of the SteamVR plugin, I didn't write it and I cannot update the plugin without breaking my project.
I don't know how to use Unity's up-to-date UI system, would you know what replaced the "GUILayer" component ?

Comment: @PierreLouisPAUGAM try to update SteamVR to latest version. If errors not will be gone - don't use latest Unity3D version, use latest supported by SteamVR version.

Answer (score 0):

It was not "replaced" it was removed because Unity's UI System is now a different. I think you should look for a newer version of this plugin.